# Understanding the following x86 assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

What is the output of the below code?

```
AND    eax, 0
CALL   $+0xA
ENTER  0, 0

LAHF    
ADD    eax, 0xC829
BSWAP  eax
SHR    eax, 0x13
```

Converting hex to decimal -

```
0xA    = 10
0xC829 = 51241
0x13   = 19
```

[Added a screenshot of the original (removed some irrelevant text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbati.jpg)

Comment: Did you look up what the instructions do? Did you run it in a debugger? What's causing you problems? PS: converting to decimal won't help you much.

Comment: There are no other instructions, its a "Shall we play a game" type of console. The debugger is failing to run this code, i have 0 understanding in Assembly, this code got me curious, that's all.

Comment: It's a nice riddle. You need to know the length of each instruction to get the destination of the relative `CALL`.

Comment: @zx485 and how i find the length of each instruction?

Comment: @zx485:  let me guess; it jumps into the middle of one of those later instructions?  Or does it simply not `ret`?   Oh, no, I just assembled with `nasm -felf32` and disassembled with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` and it jumps to the `add`.   @ Z100: you don't need to manually find instruction lengths, just assemble it (and optionally link it so you can single-step it if you  want)

Answer (score 4):

This is NASM syntax assembly.  You can assemble it with `nasm -felf64` (or `nasm -felf32` if you want) and disassemble the resulting `.o` with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` and see that the `call` jumps to the `add`.

The call target for `call $+10` is 10 bytes ahead of the *start* of the  `call` instruction: that's how `$` in NASM syntax works. The `+10` is *not* the `rel32` machine code encoding of the `call` instruction (relative to the *end* of the instruction), it's just a way to specify a target address relative to a position in the source, as an alternative to putting a label there.

---

You can even link it with `ld -o test test.o` and run the resulting static executable under GDB.  (use `starti` to run but stop at a breakpoint before the first instruction.  Use `layout reg` to see the instructions + register values).

`ld` looks for a `_start` symbol, otherwise it defaults to setting the executable's entry point to the start of the `.text` section (which is what NASM assembles into by default), so yes `nasm` + `ld` does work for single-stepping some instructions under GDB without a bunch of extra syntax needed.

Of course the executable won't exit cleanly; there's no code to make an `_exit` system call.   But we only want to  single-step it in a debugger anyway, not even call printf or anything.  You can exit GDB, or just continue and let it segfault.